# How do i group the time in and time out according to the employee number and date

Tags: php, sql, database

[attendence sql file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-X9_6aR7HzWIu-MXjl4FN4U7J7GKgYoQ)[ ][2] I try to get attendance table data (which include the emp_no ,date ,time).i want insert the above table date as emp_no,date,time in and time out.time logic is show in below.

i try sql query

```
SELECT  
          EnrolledID,
          Date,
          CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 03:00:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 12:15:00' THEN Time 
          END AS time_in ,
          CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 12:15:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 23:59:59' THEN Time 
          END AS time_out
          from attendance
          GROUP BY EnrolledID,Date
```

Output of above query

```
EnrolledID      Date                time_in                 time_out    
23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:54:40     NULL    
23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     NULL                    1899-12-30 16:01:40 
23          2019-08-02 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:42:35      NULL   
23          2019-08-02 00:00:00    NULL                     1899-12-30 16:02:53 
23          2019-08-03 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:37:41      NULL
```

Expected output.

```
EnrolledID      Date                time_in                 time_out    
    23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:54:40     1899-12-30 16:01:40 
    23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:42:35                 1899-12-30 16:01:40 
    23          2019-08-02 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:42:35     1899-12-31 16:15:33 
    23          2019-08-02 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:11:51                     1899-12-30 16:02:53 
    23          2019-08-03 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:37:41      1899-12-31 16:15:00
```

how do i fixed this issue? how do i avoid NULL value coming?

Comment: no need to concern about 1899-12-31

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is not coding part .it just show the time frame to determine the time in and time out

Comment: yes. i try solve the with the 3 days.but when be group the data one value the data be missing

Comment: The very best way to attract knowledgeable volunteers and receive fast, high-quality solutions is to generate a complete dbfiddle demo link with just enough sample data to reproduce the issue and show your failed query in it.  We see your expected result set, so that part is done properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample results don't make sense.  You have duplicates for `23`/`'2019-08-01'`, but I see no data supporting such a duplicate.

I suspect that what you really want is aggregation, something like this:

```
SELECT EnrolledID, Date,
       MIN(Time) as time_in,
       NULLIF(MAX(Time), MIN(Time)) as time_out
FROM attendance
GROUP BY EnrolledID, Date;
```

This assumes at most two rows per date per enrollee.

Comment: it work but have the small problem.time out period may occur in next data between 00:00:00  and 03:00:00 also should be consider as time out

Comment: any way thank you very much

Comment: how do manage above condition? (Time >= '00:00:00' && Time < '03:00:00') must be identify as the previous day time out